# Loop in bash terminal and apply command

Tags: bash, xslt

I am trying to set up some script using the terminal in Mac where I am trying to do the following steps:

Count all occurrences in an XML file of a specific element.
Apply a stylesheet that will create a new subset of the original file and each new file should contain a subset of 10 elements.

The script would be something like below, for which I need help as I am new in bash scripting.

```
countElements =$(grep "<test>" /Users/test/Downloads/xml.xml | wc -l)
start = 0;
for f in /Users/test/Downloads/*.xml; 
{have a loop here saying while start <= countelements apply the following command}
     do xsltproc --stringparam param1 $countElements param2 $start transform2.xsl data2.xml > output$start$countElements.html
start = start + 10
{end while}
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? (untested)

```
dir='/Users/test/Downloads'

countElements=$(grep '<test>' "$dir"/xml.xml | wc -l)
start=0
for f in "$dir"/*.xml  
do
    while (( start <= countelements )) 
    do
        xsltproc --stringparam param1 $countElements param2 $start transform2.xsl data2.xml > output$start$countElements.html
        start=$((start + 10))
    done
done
```

Spaces are not allowed around an `=` in an assignment, and a trailing semi-colon `;` has no effect.  I used the `dir` variable for flexibility.